# SEO Friendly URLs in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am completely new to this Framework. Hence, any help is really appreciated. I am developing a website using Ruby on Rails Framework (Currently it is in beta phase); however, there are 2 major issue I am facing

1. URLs - all the URLs are having #! because of which Search Engines are not crawling and indexing the same
2. Content on the website is not getting crawled or indexed

Please help.

Comment: Can please tell how URLs looks like right now?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [free railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) or a nicer one, but [paid](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised)

Regarding your content not being indexed or crawled, did you setup proper robots.txt on your server?